# open an exe which is on remote machine using Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

open an exe which is on remote machine and not on my local machine which has hub and node using java selenium,I do not know if that's possible or not.I am looking for a slution.

Comment: "Open an exe" how? Do you mean launch the executable? If so, which machine do you want to launch it on?

Answer (score 1):

you can use psexec to do it.

Download from here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that on the machine where you want to launch your exe you will run some Webserver running some web application that also could be written on java or any other language. That web App should expose an API (REST API is one of the popular options) that woulsd receive request and upon that request will launch your exe. Now on your remote machine your java app (or any other app or just a brouser) will need to send a regular HTTP request to your webserver, and your web app will do the launch